# pyenv not found when opening terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I receive the following error when I run a new terminal

```
Comando «pyenv» non trovato, si intendeva forse:

  comando «pyvenv» da deb python3-venv
  comando «p7env» da deb libnss3-tools

Provare: sudo apt install <nome deb>


Comando «pyenv» non trovato, si intendeva forse:

  comando «pyvenv» da deb python3-venv
  comando «p7env» da deb libnss3-tools

Provare: sudo apt install <nome deb>
```

which can be roughly translated to

```
Comand «pyenv» not found, maybe you meant:

  comand «pyvenv» from deb python3-venv
  comand «p7env» from deb libnss3-tools

try: sudo apt install <name deb>


Comand «pyenv» not found, maybe you meant:

  comand «pyvenv» from deb python3-venv
  comand «p7env» from deb libnss3-tools

try: sudo apt install <name deb>
```

The problem is that pyenv sems to work fine when I used it so I'm not sure what's happening here.

To clarify, I'm using ubuntu 1.18

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Then:

```
exec bash
```

See [Configure your shell's environment for Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout)

Comment: for some reasons, this makes the execution of .bashrc very slow... I have a fairly old machine, but it's an i7